# show particular data in pop up modal in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

this is regarding Vue.js question

i'm trying to open bootstrap model form inside the Vue template 
i use two vue template components,

- this sub component call inside this competence and pass data from this to sub component
- this component use for show particular (load one by one products) model data

so i need to show one by one products data on the model form (when product 1 show name 'Abc') like this

but i cant do this.. all implementation are done and working fine
but cant show the particular data on the model form

show it only first loop value (i have 3 products all load in the table,but when click edit button first product show correctly,but click 2nd product show first product data)

but when i call console.log function and view when open the model show particular data in the console, but not showing its on the model form

why it that

i put my code segment in the below

example-component

```
  <tbody >
     <tr div v-for="invoices in invoice">
         <th class="invoice_name ">{{invoices.p_name}}</th>                       
         <td class="unit">
         <sub-com :pID=invoices.p_id :invoice=invoices :invoiceID=invoice_id></sub-com>
         </td>      
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

sub-com

```
<template>
 <div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <a href="#" @click="refundMethod(invoice)">Refund</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="modal fade" id="refundModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addNewLabel"
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <form>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input v-model="form.name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

this is sub.vue script segment

```
<script>

export default{

  data(){
    return{                  
    form: {     
      name:''                  
        }
    }
  },        

  props: {    
    pID: String,
    invoiceID:String,
    invoice:{},     
}
methods: {
  refundMethod(invoices){
    this.form.name = invoices.p_name;
    console.log(invoices.p_name);
    $('#refundModel').modal('show');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues that might clear things up.

First you need to add a key to your template `v-for` loop:

`<tr v-for="invoices in invoice" :key="invoices.p_id">`

Second you are using jquery to trigger the modal which could work but you will have to generate unique ids for each div:

`<div :id="'refundModel_'+pID">`

A more Vue way to do this is to use the bootstrap `data-show` attribute and link it to a Boolean `modal` property in your data:

`<div :data-show="modal" :id="'refundModel_'+pID">`

```
export default {

 data(){
    return{ 
      modal : false,                 
      form: {     
        name:''                  
         }
      }
 },        
 props: {    
    pID: String,
    invoiceID: String,
    invoice: Object,     
 }
 methods: {
   refundMethod(invoices){
     this.form.name = invoices.p_name;
     console.log(invoices.p_name);
     this.toggleModal()
   }
   toggleModal () {
     this.modal = !this.modal
   }
 }
}
```